# Arduino NANO - not showing in device manager

Tags: arduino

If somebody solved this issue, please send me link.

My issue:

I bought 2 arduino nanos (http://www.ebay.com/itm/311064700128?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT)

When I plugged them into PC, Led started blinking. I decided to try and test it so I wrote a program blink led with a bigger delays etc. I changed things as I should (like 328, arduino nano setting etc.)
When I open device manager, ports there is not even an arduino here!
And still it doesnt wat to upload itself! My chip mega328P AU1451 (its written under name)

Error message: 
Quote

> Arduino: 1.6.4 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328"
>
> Sketch uses 1 070 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30
>   720 bytes.
>
> Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2 039
>   bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2 048 bytes.
>
> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>
> avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9b
>
> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>
> avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9b
>
> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>
> avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9b
>
> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>
> avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9b
>
> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>
> avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9b
>
> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>
> avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9b
>
> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>
> avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9b
>
> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>
> avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9b
>
> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>
> avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9b
>
> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>
> avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x9b
>
> Problem uploading to board.  See
>   http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
>
> This report would have more information with   "Show verbose output
>   during compilation"   enabled in File > Preferences.

I tried to change programmer settings and it has told this:

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM1": Prístup je odmietnutý.

(prístup je odmietnutý means acces is denied)

Any ideas how to solve this? Arduino forums didnt answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino clone device you have linked to uses the CH340 chip as its USB serial adapter. You need to obtain the drivers from the [Chinese manufacturer](http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_EXE.html) or some other site. There are a number of blogs that provide information about using these clones ([example](http://kiguino.moos.io/2014/12/31/how-to-use-arduino-nano-mini-pro-with-CH340G-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html)). Provided the driver is installed it should then appear as a standard serial port device and can then be used in the same way as a genuine Arduino device.

Comment: I actually installed a driver for it and still nothing. Possible that I had 2 broken cables (usb) in row?

Comment: They may not have the bootloader installed. If the correct driver is installed then the device should appear as COMn but would not respond to the programming protocol. If that is the case then you will need to install the bootloader using either a programmer device or another arduino programmed to be a programmer.  (http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard)